# Combining a Spring application with an express & node backend

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot, express, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to developing with multiple tech stacks so I was wondering if it was possible to combine the two together?

For example, with an express backend that already maps requests like `/about` and `/contact` I want to have a spring application that maps a request for `/service` in its `MainController` and use other classes like `MainService.java`.

I currently have a social-media type of application built on Node and an AWS image upload app built with Spring so I was curious if it was possible to connect these two apps so that users can upload images using the Spring app.

If this is possible, what other benefits can it provide? or is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two applications are **restful** u can turn in **micro-services** Architecture to use a **service discovery** which can recognize the two applications and another application to be the **Api gateway** that can play the role of proxy to redirect requests.

- [multiple languages micro-services](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/ive-heard-i-can-use-any-language-for-each-microservice-is-that-correct-6bc63ca910db)
- [service discovery](https://medium.com/@jamesemyn/service-discovery-in-microsrvice-cbd54afb94f3)
- [api gateway](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/what-is-an-api-gateway-8f0c4a1a1d39).

> Otherwise if u are apps are not restful u can simply make a **http requests** to link them.